# Why pandas merge is skipping some rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have df1, df2 who share mutual column (time) where df2.time ∈ df1.also tdf1 shape is (2353X11) and df2 shape is (57X1). I'm trying to create df3 using merge method to extract some rows from df1 based on rows of df2. issue is df3 is missing some rows even though both df1 & df2 are float64 and have mutual values. 
df3 shape should have 57 rows also but I get 54 only!

df1

[image: df1]

df2

[image: df2]

```
def pressure_filter (noisydata, reducedtime, filcutoff, tzero):
    b,a = sig.butter(2, filcutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    noisydata['p_lowcut'] = sig.filtfilt(b, a, noisydata.p_noisy)
    noisydata.at[0,'p_lowcut'] = noisydata.at[0,'p_noisy']
    noisydata['p_lowcut_ma'] = noisydata['p_lowcut'].rolling(20, center = True).mean()
    noisydata['p_lowcut_ma'] = noisydata.apply(lambda row: row['p_lowcut'] if 
                                            np.isnan(row['p_lowcut_ma'])
                                            else row['p_lowcut_ma'], axis=1)

    datared = pd.merge(noisydata, reducedtime, on=['time'], how='inner')
    return datared
```

Comment: What is `df1` and `df2` in your code? Your `merge` within code has `noisydata` and `reducedtime` as dataframe's names. Can't figure out the correspondence

Comment: noisydata=df1 and reduced time =df2. the function is desined to apply a filter to noisydata then create a subset (datared) of the filtered data.